# LOMP Server /Wordpress / PHP compatiblity issues in

Tags: php, wordpress, compatibility, multisite, openlitespeed

I am updating a multi-site WordPress(WP) setup and migrating it to OLS (Openlitespeed server) from Apache.
Currently, I am facing issues in PHP compatibility, some WP plugins use 7.4 as base PHP and some use 7.2.
Since most of the plugins are business crucial, is there any way where we can give PHP 7.2 and 8.0.0 and all the versions in between by these plugins?

How to ensure that all the compatibility are matched by installing all versions of PHP old and new ones to come.

Comment: you mean plugin A to run on PHP72 , plugin B to run on PHP80 ...etc ?

Answer (score 0):

Plugins should be forward-compatible with respect to php versions. That is, if you have a plugin requiring php 7.2 and another requiring 7.4, you must use 7.4 or a later version of php to run your site.

The plugin directory says "requires at least *some version* of php" for each listed plugin.

There's no way to use multiple versions of php to run a single WordPress installation, even a multi site one.

Test carefully before you start using php8. There may be some breaking changes affecting some code (plugins and themes) in the WordPress ecosystem.

I build my plugins to support php 5.6 or later. This is not because I hope my users will use that miserably obsolete version, but because I don't want to worry about whether some users will not be able to use them.